# Windows VST on Linux?

Tags: sound, software-installation, audio-jack, audio-recording, vst

I spent researching and trying this for about a whole day. I have some windows VST such as Softube, BIAS FX and Surfer EQ that I'd like to use with Reaper (running on WINE). There were some different apps that promised to run windows VST but I could not make any of them work. I must say I'm newbie in Linux and using terminal but I tried my best. If someone could walk me through how to make these VSTs work I'd be so greatful!

Comment: You can easily check the WineHQ database by googling "winehq software".

Comment: Yes, I did, none of these are listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Windows version of Reaper "relatively" easy to work on Ubuntu with low-latency-kernel. With Cadence for jack and the jack/wine bridge you can pass the routes to Reaper in a bit more comfortable way than configuring each program on its own. But don't get your hopes up. I was at first very happy that it worked at all but soon reality started to kick in. There was simply no configuration of jack i could find which didn't had a latency to high or broke the connection now and than. It was besides of this not very stable and crashed from time to time.

Let me spare you a great amount of ass-pain: Don't use linux for DAW stuff. I was really pissed at this realization but sinking almost a week into this fathomless pit i was pretty burned out and didn't bother to use Windows 7 again (10s horrible updates brought me to try linux-DAW again xD).

Comment: I also spent a great amount of time trying to figure and ended up giving up on Linux because of this. Running Win 7.